# Q/KDB: How do you call system commands in a lambda/function

Tags: kdb

How do you call system commands in a lambda/function?

E.g. I would like to load a q script through .z.ts

Trying .z.ts:{\l myScript.q} does not work. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the loading system function in the format

```
system "l [x]"
```

For example:

```
.z.ts:{system "l myscript.q"}
```

You can find some information about using system commands, like so, here:
https://kx.com/blog/kdb-q-insights-scripting-with-q/